# Ajax request response code 419 even csrf token is available in request

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a simple ajax request which is returning 419 even csrf token is available in both the ajax setup header and inform data as well here is my code.

```
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('_token', $("input[name='_token']").val());
        formData.append('request_id', $('#request_id').val());


var request = $.ajax({
            url: appUrl + "/admin/schedule-detailing-requests",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            // headers: headers

        });
```

Comment: Have you included the csrf meta tag in your master file?
And why are you including the token twice in one ajax?

Comment: Double check, if you have setup csrf token in your main layout/index. Fastest way is to enter this in browser dev console:
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');